# Как переслать сообщение вместе с клавиатурой (кнопкой) в Telegram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Я пишу бота на python Aiogram. У меня есть сообщение которое отправляет бот и к  которому приделана inline клавиатура. Когда пытаюсь пересылать это сообщение, пересылается только само сообщение, но не клавиатура. Я пытался пересылать сообщение через copy_message() и forward_message().

Я знаю что у функции copy_message() есть атрибут reply_markup через который можно добавить клавиатуру к сообщению. Но я не знаю как её скопировать из другого сообщения. Важно что я должен её скопировать именно из сообщения а не взять её в коде.

Итого: мне нужно либо скопировать клавиатуру из сообщения, либо переслать клавиатуру вместе с сообщением.

Comment: Насколько мне известно - `json` ответ от сервера telegram содержит внутри себя объекты клавиатуры - я думаю можно что-то придумать, не создавая клавиатуру в коде

Answer (score 0):

Просто храните клавиатуру сообщения в отдельной переменной, и где Вам нужно, подключайте. Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```py
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

...

reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(InlineKeyboardButton(text="Click me", callback_data="test_handler"))
... 

await bot.copy_message(chat_id=123456789, from_chat_id=987654321, message_id=123, reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Клавиатуру и значения измените на свои :)